# Tools to automate webservices testing

Tags: web-services, automated-tests

I need some help with regards to webservices automation testing.

I have around 30-40 scripts, so every time that i do any change in my code, i want to automate that testing

I have heard about SoapUI NG. Is there any other tool that you could suggest?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try Karate. or use Rest Assured

Answer (score -1):

Depending on which language the scripts are written, there's numerous ways to do this.

You can use JUNIT and TeamCity to achieve continuous integration, 
You can use ITKO-LISA TeamCity
You can use Soap UI, Jenkins

Here's an example, the core idea is the same.
You need a build script that can trigger your tests (ANT)
And a CI server (TeamCity) to trigger the build.

https://impeccabletester.wordpress.com/2015/11/01/itkolisa-integration-with-teamcity/